# Error in Connection to MySQL with a publish App of C# .NETCore 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an application that connects in MySql server of my own database register and log in users, when i run it from IDE works fine but when i exports the app to publish it throws an EntityframeworkCore error, this package is not even installed, i have disabled the firewall and change the appsettings.json to all configurations as possible, i don't know what i'm missing here
here is the error when i do a POST in the exported app

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
  An error occurred using the connection to database 'usuariodb' on server 'localhost'.

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
  An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'UsuarioApi.Data.UserDbContext'.
  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
   ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
   ---> System.NotSupportedException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_CodeBase()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
     at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
   ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
   ---> System.NotSupportedException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_CodeBase()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
     at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HMFBPG06USN4", Request id "0HMFBPG06USN4:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.)
   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
   ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
   ---> System.NotSupportedException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_CodeBase()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
     at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
     at UsuarioApi.Services.LoginService.LogaUsuario(LoginRequest request)
     at UsuarioApi.Controllers.LoginController.LogaUsuario(LoginRequest request)
     at lambda_method1(Closure , Object , Object[] )
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var conString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsuarioConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(conString));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>>(opt =>
            {
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        services.AddScoped<CadastroService, CadastroService>();
        services.AddScoped<LogoutService, LogoutService>();
        services.AddScoped<LoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<TokenService, TokenService>();
        services.AddScoped<EmailService, EmailService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Connection String

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"UsuarioConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=usuariodb;user=root;password=admin"
```

}

Comment: Could this be the culprit? `CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44511) thread will help?

Comment: so if i dont publish a single archive maybe work?